# Express-validator input sanitize inside a middleware or router callback?

Tags: node.js, express-validator

I'm trying to improve the security of my express app by using the express-validator package, I figured out that I could use it in two different ways.

The first inside a middleware:

```
const {check}=require("express-validator");
app.post(
  "/random-post",
  [
    check("email").isEmail(),
  ],
  (req, res) => {
    //some code
  })
```

Second inside of the router's call back:

```
app.post("/random-post",(req,res,next)=>{
   check(req.body.email).isEmail()
})
```

Which of the two are most used or maybe should I use both?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best practice here is to do the validation and sanitazion before reaching the controller. In the same block of logic you can also check if there are any validation errors and return an error. This way the controller is never reached, so code in your controller is never executed. I updated your example below:

```js
const {check} = require('express-validator');

app.post(
  '/random-post', [
    check('email').isEmail(),
    (req, res, next) => {
      const errors = validationResult(req);
      if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(422).json({
          errors: errors.array()
        });
      }
      next();
    }
  ],
  (req, res) => {
    //some code in your controller
  }
);
```